# UWP Background Media Playback

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, uwp, background-audio

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to set up the background audio player in my app but I'm stuck at step one. There is no capability called `Background Audio Task` in my manifest file. Adding it manually doesn't do any good either since these events described in another step aren't even available/shown in properties window/shown by IntelliSense.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that page was fairly straightforward. As mentioned on the page, the capability is "Background Media Playback".

[image: Screenshot]

If you still don't see *that* in the list, then it's probably because you do not have the Anniversay SDK (version 14393) or later installed. The Anniversary update introduced a new [single process model](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/07/background-activity-with-the-single-process-model/) for background execution, which that webpage is walking you through.

Comment: Well, there is no capability called *Background Audio Task*, which I thought was the issue. What min SDK version are you targeting? Are you saying that `Application.EnteredBackground` doesn't exist for you? This was added in Windows 10 version 1607 (the Anniversary update). What version of Windows 10 are you running?

Comment: I'm up to date on both my PCs, but I have only  [these two versions of the SDK installed](http://imgur.com/a/2PtLv). Will redownloading VS help in this case?

Comment: You will need SDK 14393 or later to get the Anniversary APIs, including `EnteredBackground`. I can't say for sure if this will enable the Background Media Playback capability in the manifest, but it likely will since the Anniversary update did introduce the single process model for background audio which that webpage talks about, and you will need to update the SDK to get the new APIs anyway.